# Hidden div blocks content on site

Tags: javascript, css

I have a cookie consent function on my site but even when its hidden its somehow blocking the links behind it. How do I make the consent window not to block the links behind. 
I have two cases that needs to be handled: 
1) User accepts/denies the Consent, the div disappears but is still blocking content
2) User has already given consent when entering the site. The div is not visible but is blocking the content.

**Consent DIVs:**

```
    <div class="fixed-bottom p-4">
    <div class="toast bg-dark text-white w-100 mw-100" role="alert" data-autohide="false">
        <div class="toast-body p-4 d-flex flex-column">
            <h4>Cookie Warning</h4>
            <p>
                This website stores data such as cookies to enable site functionality including analytics and personalization. By using this website, you automatically accept that we use cookies.
                Read more about our cookies <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Cookies">HERE</a>
            </p>
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mr-3" id="btnDeny">
                    Deny
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnAccept">
                    Accept
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS. Script**

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

function cookieConsent() {
    if (!getCookie('allowCookies')) {
        $('.toast').toast('show')
    }
}

try {
    $('#btnDeny').click(() => {
        eraseCookie('allowCookies')
        $('.toast').toast('hide')
    })
}
catch (err) {
    // Ignore
}

try {
    $('#btnAccept').click(() => {
        setCookie('allowCookies', '1', 7)
        $('.toast').toast('hide')
    })
}
catch (err) {
    // Ignore
}




// load
cookieConsent()
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap's toast component or some JQuery plugin?

Comment: @SaschaM78 I belive that to be the JQuery version but im not 100% sure. I got it from here: https://www.codeply.com/p/azCmarhM9X

Comment: AFAIK JQuery-UI does not have a `.toast()` method in the original version so I assume there is an external JS file included in your project. Could you check for a `<script src="..toast.js"></script>" or similar?

Comment: Did i search in my project, its Bootstrap.bundle.js its jusing

Comment: I think it's due to the `<div class="fixed-bottom p-4">` that will be `position:fixed` on the bottom which will leave a block of 48px without any content.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/fd0hLbw2/6/) to show the problem. I added a background color to the fixed container so you see what remains after dismissing the warning.

Comment: Hmm now i'm getting closer. It looks like its the link that is blocking the content after hiding the div. https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/fd0hLbw2/6/ if you put the pointer somewhere around the blue area you can see that it show the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215527/discussion-between-sascham78-and-daniel-bjork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging in Chat we found the underlying problem: after the cookie got set the toast message got discarded but the container around it - `<div class="fixed-bottom p-4">` never got removed and remained invisibly over the underlying content. The solution was to hide it as well when checking for a cookie or setting the cookie:

```
$('.toast').toast('hide');
$('.toast').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, try setting `pointer-events: none;` on the outer `div` and `pointer-events: all;` on any inner-elements that you want to be interactive. Not sure if that's what you're after but hopefully it helps.

Comment: When i click the Deny or Accept button the div hides but its still blocking the content underneath the dialog. Or when you already accepted the Consent the div is hidden from the begining but still blocking the content. What I want is the entire div to not block the content after its hidden.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: No, I'm actually doubting that disabling the pointer events on the consent divs is a proper solution to the problem. Its not really what i want to do.

Comment: What are you using for `.toast('hide')`? Is it a jQuery plugin?

Comment: bootstrap. mentioned above in the comments